# How to update an existing SQLite db table data with new android app update?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, csv

I recently launched an app on the android app store that contained a SQLite database.

I am now attempting to release an update of the app, and want to add more data into the existing database, however have come a bit unstuck. I have read answers on SO that outline making changes to the database itself, however I want my tables and columns to stay the same, only add new data in.

The data that i want to add to the database is pulled from CSV files in the `Raw` file, and originally loaded into the database when the user registers for the app.

I have a feeling I am going to need to implement the `onUpgrade` method, however should I be adding the new data from the CSV files in at that point as well? Is it a matter of simple updating the database version and using the `onUpgrade` to load the new data?

I am fairly new to SQLite DB, so any help would be hugely appreciated.

**CourseDBHelper Code**

```
public class CourseDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CourseDB";

// Create two table names
private static final String TABLE_COURSES = "courses";

// Universities Table Columns names
private static final String COURSE_NAME = "Course_name";
private static final String UNI_NAME = "Uni_name";
private static final String COURSE_DURATION = "Duration";
private static final String COURSE_STUDY_MODE = "Study_mode";
private static final String COURSE_QUALIFICATION = "Qualification";
private static final String COURSE_ENTRY_STANDARDS = "Entry_standards";
private static final String COURSE_GRADUATE_PROSPECTS = "Graduate_prospects";
private static final String COURSE_STUDENT_SATISFACTION = "Student_satisfaction";


private String CREATE_COURSES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE courses" +
        "(" +
        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        "Course_name TEXT NOT NULL," +
        "Uni_name TEXT NOT NULL," +
        "Duration TEXT NOT NULL," +
        "Study_mode TEXT NOT NULL," +
        "Qualification TEXT NOT NULL," +
        "Entry_standards TEXT NOT NULL," +
        "Graduate_prospects TEXT NOT NULL," +
        "Student_satisfaction TEXT NOT NULL" +
        ");";

private static final String[] COLUMNS = {
        COURSE_NAME,
        UNI_NAME,
        COURSE_DURATION,
        COURSE_STUDY_MODE,
        COURSE_QUALIFICATION,
        COURSE_ENTRY_STANDARDS,
        COURSE_GRADUATE_PROSPECTS,
        COURSE_STUDENT_SATISFACTION
};

public CourseDBHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// TODO: REMOVED NOT NULL FROM EVERY COLUMN FOR TEST PURPOSES, WILL NEED TO BE READDED
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL(CREATE_COURSES_TABLE);
}

public void deleteAll()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete("courses", null, null);
    db.execSQL("delete from " + "courses");
    db.close();
}

// Getting one course by course name and uni name
public Course getCourse(String courseName, String uniName) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_COURSES, COLUMNS, " Course_name = ? AND Uni_name = ?",
            new String[]{courseName, uniName},
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();


    Course course = new Course();

    /*

    System.out.println(cursor.getString(0));
    System.out.println(cursor.getString(1));
    System.out.println(cursor.getString(2));
    System.out.println(cursor.getString(3));
    System.out.println(cursor.getString(4));
    System.out.println(cursor.getString(5));
    System.out.println(cursor.getString(6));
    */

    course.setCourseName(cursor.getString(0));
    course.setUniversity(cursor.getString(1));
    course.setCourseDuration(cursor.getString(2));
    course.setStudyMode(cursor.getString(3));
    course.setQualification(cursor.getString(4));
    course.setEntryStandards(cursor.getString(5));
    course.setGradProspects(cursor.getString(6));
    course.setStudentSatisfaction(cursor.getString(7));


    return course;

}

public void addCourse(Course course)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COURSE_NAME, course.getCourseName());
    values.put(UNI_NAME, course.getUniversity());
    values.put(COURSE_DURATION, course.getCourseDuration());
    values.put(COURSE_STUDY_MODE, course.getStudyMode());
    values.put(COURSE_QUALIFICATION, course.getQualification());
    values.put(COURSE_ENTRY_STANDARDS, course.getEntryStandards());
    values.put(COURSE_GRADUATE_PROSPECTS, course.getGradProspects());
    values.put(COURSE_STUDENT_SATISFACTION, course.getStudentSatisfaction());

    db.insert(TABLE_COURSES,
            null, //nullColumnHack
            values);

    db.close();
}


public ArrayList<Course> getAllCourses()
{
    ArrayList<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
    // 1. build the query
    String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_COURSES;
    // 2. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    // 3. go over each row, build course and add it to list
    Course course;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        cursor.moveToNext();
        do{
            course = new Course();
            course.setCourseName(cursor.getString(1));
            course.setUniversity(cursor.getString(2));
            course.setCourseDuration(cursor.getString(3));
            course.setStudyMode(cursor.getString(4));
            course.setQualification(cursor.getString(5));
            course.setEntryStandards(cursor.getString(6));
            course.setGradProspects(cursor.getString(7));
            course.setStudentSatisfaction(cursor.getString(8));

            // Add course to courses list
            courses.add(course);
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return courses
    return courses;
}

public int getDBCount()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String count = "SELECT count(*) FROM courses";
    Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(count, null);
    mcursor.moveToFirst();
    int icount = mcursor.getInt(0);
    return icount;
}

public void deleteCourse(Course course) {

    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // 2. delete
    db.delete("courses", //table name
            "Course_name = ? AND Uni_name = ?",  // selections
            new String[] { course.getCourseName(), course.getUniversity() }); //selections args

    // 3. close
    db.close();
}



@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {


}
}
```

**Method that loads data from CSV file to SQlite DB**

```
public void populateCourseDatabase(int id) {

        // NOW POPULATE THE COURSE DATABASE FILE
inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.coursesone);


        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String word;
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

        try{
            while((word = reader.readLine()) != null){

                Log.d(TAG, "constructing Course object from: " + word);

                String[] segment = word.split(cvsSplitBy);

                Course course = new Course();
                course.setCourseName(segment[0]);
                course.setUniversity(segment[1]);
                course.setCourseDuration(segment[2]);
                course.setStudyMode(segment[3]);
                course.setQualification(segment[4]);
                course.setEntryStandards(segment[5]);
                course.setGradProspects(segment[6]);
                course.setStudentSatisfaction(segment[7]);


                myCourseDBHelper.addCourse(course);

                progressBar.setProgress(count);

                count = count + 1;

                System.out.println("Sucessfully added: " + course.toString());
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("SOMETHING WENT WRONG");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() and onUpgrade() callbacks are invoked when the database is actually opened, for example by a call to getWritableDatabase().onCreate() is only run when the database file did not exist and was just created. onUpgrade() is only called when the database file exists but the stored version number is lower than requested in constructor.Increment the database version so that onUpgrade() is invoked. 
Example pseudo code below

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    switch(oldVersion) {

    case 1:
        //upgrade logic from version 1 to 2
    case 2:
        //upgrade logic from version 2 to 3
    case 3:
        //upgrade logic from version 3 to 4
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException(
        "onUpgrade() with unknown oldVersion " + oldVersion);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a way i could tell which database version the user has, ie; IF the user is UPDATING the application, add new data to the db, however if the user has installed for the first time, add ALL data to the db?

Comment: You need to change the version number passed in OnCreate method in Database class where you extend SqliteOpen Helper. When new version app is installed it will call OnUpgrade(..) method, here you write all your queries.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, i'm starting to see what you mean. So i need to increment the `DATABASE_VERSION` int at the top of the class to 2, and then write an `if else` statement that says `if DATABASE_VERSION == 2 { //add all new data`. Am i on the right lines?